# Are pysa users expected to copy configuration files?

Tags: static-analysis, taint, pyre-check, pysa

Facebook's Pysa tool looks useful, in the Pysa tutorial exercises they refer to files that are provided in the pyre-check repository using a relative path to include a path outside of the exercise directory.

https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check/blob/master/pysa_tutorial/exercise1/.pyre_configuration

```
{
    "source_directories": ["."],
    "taint_models_path": ["."],
    "search_path": [
        "../../stubs/"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        ".*/integration_test/.*"
    ]
}
```

There are stubs provided for Django in the pyre-check repository which if I know the path where pyre check is installed I can hard-code in my `.pyre_configuration` and get something working but another developer may install pyre-check differently.

Is there a better way to refer to these provided stubs or should I copy them to the repository I'm working on?

Answer (score 2):

Many projects have a standard development environment, allowing for hard coded paths in the `.pyre_configuration` file. These will usually point into the `venv`, or some other standard install location for dependencies.

For projects without a standard development environment, you could trying incorporating [`pyre init`](https://pyre-check.org/docs/getting-started#setting-up-a-project) into your setup scripts. `pyre init` will setup a fresh `.pyre_configuration` file with paths that correspond to the current install of `pyre`. For additional configuration you want to add on top of the generated `.pyre_configuration` file (such as a pointer to local taint models), you can hand write a [`.pyre_configuration.local`](https://pyre-check.org/docs/configuration#local-configurations), which will act as an overlay and overwrite/add to the content of `.pyre_configuration`.

Answer (score 1):

Pyre-check looks for the stubs in the directory specified by the `typeshed` directive in the configuration file.

The easiest way is to move stubs provided for Django in the pyre-check repository to the `typeshed` directory that is in the pyre-check directory.

For example, if you have installed pyre-check to the `~/.local/lib` directory, move the `django` directory from `~/.local/lib/pyre_check/stubs` to `~/.local/lib/pyre_check/typeshed/third_party/2and3/` and make sure your .pyre_configuration file will look like this:

```
{
  "source_directories": ["~/myproject"],
  "taint_models_path": "~/myproject/taint",
  "typeshed": "~/.local/lib/pyre_check/typeshed"
}
```

In this case, your Django stubs directory will be ~/.local/lib/pyre_check/typeshed/third_parth/2and3/django

Pyre-check uses the following algorithm to traverse across the `typeshed` directory:

1. If it contains the `third_party` subdirectory, it uses a legacy method: enters just the two subdirectories: `stdlib` and `third_party` and there looks for any subdirectory except those with names starting with `2` but not `2and3`, and looks for the modules in those subdirectories like `2and3`, e.g. in `third_party/2and3/`
2. Otherwise, it enters the subdirectories `stubs` and `stdlib`, and looks for modules there, e.g. in `stubs/`, but not in `stubs/2and3/`.

That's why specifying multiple paths may be perplexing and confusing, and the easiest way is to setup the `typeshed` directory to `~/.local/lib/pyre_check/typeshed/` and move `django` to `third_parth/2and3`, so it will be `~/.local/lib/pyre_check/typeshed/third_parth/2and3/django`.

Also don't forget to copy the `.pysa` files that you need to the `taint_models_path` directory. Don't set it up to the directory of the Pyre-check, create your own new directory and copy only those files that are relevant to you.